# How to change screen resolution of Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, screen-resolution

I am using 7" TFT LCD Display with the Raspberry pi, can anyone tell how i can change the screen resolution of Raspberry Pi and what should be the resolution for the 7" TFT LCD Display.

Comment: Depends on the operating system and the specific screen.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I made the following changes in the `/boot/config.txt` file, to support my 7" TFT LCD.

Uncomment "disable_overscan=1"

```
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
Overscan_top=10
Overscan_bottom=24

Framebuffer_width=480
Framebuffer_height=320

Sdtv_mode=2
Sdtv_aspect=2
```

I used [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRLYYWv5EVs) as a guide.

Comment: Looking to change the actual resolution. I have the overscan done, but want the buttons and everything to be bigger.

Comment: @mpromonet Suggest changing your comment adding that the /boot/config.txt needs to be changed... I had to search for the info.

Comment: In the link, http://elinux.org/RPiconfig when you search for Video options, you'll also get hdmi_group and hdmi_mode.

Comment: /boot/config.txt moved to /boot/firmware/config.txt i think

Answer (score 126):

Just run the following simple command on *Raspberry Pi 3* running *Raspbian Jessie*.

run terminal and type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Go to: >**Advanced Option** > **Resolution** >
*just set your resolution compatible fit with your screen*.

then

```
reboot
```

If you didn't found the menu on configuration, please update your raspberry pi software configuration tool (*raspi-config*).

That's all TQ.

Comment: best solution on here for me, thanks!

Comment: This also increased the resolution I was getting on my default VNC connection on port 0.

Comment: Simple and effective, thanks! Also worked for my TeamViewer session.

Comment: Clean and simple working solution, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without rebooting?

Comment: I updated everything, but when I select **Resolution** and hit `Return`, it sends me back to the start, where I have to select **Advanced Option** again.

Comment: I just find it incredible that this setting is just not under the appearance settings.

Comment: This solution isn't up-to-date anymore, as there's no resolution item under 'Advanced' anymore.

Answer (score 12):

If you are like me using a TFT that is connected via SPI (e. g. [PiTFT 2.8" 320x240](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1601)) driven by [FBTFT](https://github.com/notro/fbtft) in combination with [fbcp](https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) to utilise hardware accelerated video decoding (using omxplayer) like it is descriped [here](https://github.com/watterott/RPi-Display/blob/master/docu/FAQ.md#how-to-mirrorcopy-the-hdmi-output-to-the-display). You should add the following into the `/boot/config.txt` to force the output to HDMI and set the resolution to 320x240:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

Comment: I tried several different things but this finally worked for me on my 10.1" 1024x600 display.  I changed the 320 240 to my resolution and it looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint with "hdmi_cvt"! For some reason that was also required for my 7" display to use the correct resolution although it was simply connected through HDMI. Without it, it just cut about 20% of the right side and it wasn't overscan.

Comment: Well, this didn't work for me. Just like you I have 2.8 piTFT display and I am trying to switch it over to HDMI output for now and then switch again to the PiTFT display. No matter what I do Rasberry PI only sends the output to the PiTFT display not the monitor.

Answer (score 12):

As other comments here pointed out, you'll need to uncomment `disable_overscan=1`
in /boot/config.txt

if you are using [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) (this is what im using), you'll find in the end of the file a set of default settings that has `disable_overscan=0` attribute. you'll need to change its value to 1, and re-boot.

Comment: Even though this answer has 7 upvote, I couldn't get anything out of the HDMI output after uncommenting that line in config.txt

Comment: This worked for me - I was stuck with 593x4xx resolution until I disabled that - and then it worked great :)

Answer (score 6):

You can change the display resolution graphically (without using Terminal) on Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) using following window.

Application Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > System > Set Resolution.

[Click to view screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9CyN.jpg)

Comment: I know in some of the PI's OS, set resolution option is available. I have a Pi running Jessie and it doesn't have set resolution option. What should I do?

Comment: I don't have a set resolution option either

Answer (score 5):

Default Rpi resolution is : 1366x768 if i'm not mistaken.

You can change it though.

You will find all the information about it in this link.

http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Search "hdmi mode" on that page.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

TV Sony Bravia KLV-32T550A
Below mention config works greatly
You should add the following into the /boot/config.txt to force the output to HDMI and set the

```
resolution 82   1920x1080   60Hz    1080p

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_boost=7
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_drive=1
```

Comment: I got my 2.8 pitft display successfully working on my raspberry pi, but now I need to switch it over to HDMI output on the monitor temporarily and then switch it back to Pitft display. So, I tried your answer and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After uncommenting 
disable_overscan=1
follow my lead. In the link, http://elinux.org/RPiconfig when you search for Video options, you'll also get hdmi_group and hdmi_mode. For, hdmi_group choose 1 if you're using you TV as an video output or choose 2 for monitors. Then in hdmi_mode, you can select the resolution you want from the list. 
I chose :-
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=23
And it worked.[image]

Answer (score -2):

This works for me

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
max_usb_current=1
```

Comment: I assume this is meant to be an edit for the `/boot/config.txt` file?