# How to change screen resolution of Raspberry Pi for a 3.5'' TFT-LCD

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am using a [3.5'' TFT LCD Display](http://www.ebay.at/itm/3-5-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-320-480-RGB-Display-Case-For-Raspberry-Pi-/391223449334) with the Raspberry Pi 3 (and latest Raspbian Stretch). Can anyone please tell me how I can change the screen resolution (on the screen it says 480x320) of my Rasperry Pi.

I installed the screen like they [described in this tutorial](http://kookye.com/2016/09/04/download-raspberry-pi-3-5-touch-driver-for-raspbian-jessie/). But now I have an overflow (parts of the screen are out of the provided Screen-Size (eg. Dialogs, System settings dialog, ...). Changing the `/boot/config.txt` values to ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891235/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-raspberry-pi/23355379#23355379)):

```
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
overscan_top=10
overscan_bottom=24

framebuffer_width=480
framebuffer_height=320

sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=2
```

did not helped. Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I wanna run at a different resolution on the GPIO screen

Comment: Hi @BarrieReader, I'm sorry to tell you that I haven't tried to solve this problem since 2017 and I do not recall that I have fixed it. I hope you can find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try by changing parameters this way in /boot/config.txt..

```
hdmi_drive=2

hdmi_group=2   

hdmi_mode=16

overscan_left=20
overscan_right=12
overscan_top=10
overscan_bottom=10
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, will do and try to test it asap.

Comment: @natterstefan ,don't forget to vote if it's working for you :)

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but as soon as I will I will let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried out in 2023, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.